max_item_count breaks paginated query with python Azure Cosmos sdk?
I'm attempting to create a paginated query with FastAPI and the Python Azure Cosmos SDK. The pagination is successful when the max_item_count is specified at 1, but anything greater and there are 2 breaking scenarios.

The max_item_count is greater than total number of documents. You would think this would still work, with it fetching up to the  total number of documents in cosmos, but it is failing and returning [[], None].
The max_item_count is less than the total number of documents. This does allow pagination, but the final page is still also returning [[], None] and I believe for the same reason as scenario 1, where the max_item_count is now larger than the remaining documents to be fetched.

For example, having 7 documents in Cosmos DB, with a max_item_count of 10 will fail to return any documents.
Having 7 documents in Cosmos DB, with a max_item_count of 2 will allow pagination, but on page 4 which should return the last result it actually returns 0 documents.
Here's my code, which has been directly adapted from the samples on the SDK's github:
def paginated_query_all_items(
    container: ContainerProxy, continuation_token: str | None
) -> tuple[list | None, str | None]:
    query_iterable = container.query_items(
        query="SELECT * FROM r",
        enable_cross_partition_query=True,
        max_item_count=1,
    )

    try:
        logger.debug(f"Querying for the first page of items")
        item_pages = query_iterable.by_page(continuation_token)
        page = item_pages.next()
        cont_token = item_pages.continuation_token
        return page, cont_token
    except StopIteration:
        return [], None

I'm open to any suggestions or fixes. Hoping to avoid falling back to raw HTTP requests for the data as a last resort.
Changing the max_item_count to 1 will fetch all documents via pagination, but this won't be scalable or logical once we reach a large number of documents.
I was expecting the query to return up to max_item_count number of results, but instead it returns nothing if the max_item_count ever goes above the number of remaining documents in cosmos

It looks like you're using continuation_token incorrectly. What are you passing as a parameter into your function? It doesn't make sense for it to be passed in. The continuation_token needs to come from item_pages.continuation_token before you use it in query_iterable.by_page()

@DavidMakogon The continuation_token comes from the first page. I should have specified that this function is being called by an endpoint in FastAPI. The first page will return with the continuation token, which is sent to the frontend to then make repeat calls. The by_page() function defaults to continuation_token=None, so passing None on first call didn't seem to hurt its functionality.
